# How does sql returns all rows when concating declared column and defining it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, case

How is this possible in SQL?

```
DECLARE @liststr VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH COMMA (name)
AS
(
    SELECT 'a' 
    UNION
    SELECT 'b'
    UNION
    SELECT 'c'
    UNION
    SELECT 'd'
)
SELECT @liststr = CASE WHEN  @liststr+',' IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @liststr+',' END + name 
FROM comma

SELECT @liststr as Result
```

The above query retuns following result

```
+---------+
| Result  |
+---------+
| a,b,c,d |
+---------+
```

Where if we remove the case statement.

```
DECLARE @liststr VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH COMMA (name)
AS
(
    SELECT 'a' 
    UNION
    SELECT 'b'
    UNION
    SELECT 'c'
    UNION
    SELECT 'd'
)
SELECT @liststr = @liststr+',' + name FROM comma
SELECT @liststr as Result
```

The result is

```
+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
| NULL   |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all.  When SQL Server concatenates a string to a `NULL` value, the value is `NULL`.

If you set the value to an empty string first, then both will return the same values:

```
DECLARE @liststr VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @liststr = '';
```

Two notes:

- Use `union all` rather than `union`, unless you explicitly want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- When running a query, the results are in an arbitrary order.  If you want a particular order, then use `order by`.

Note that [Erland Sommarskog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/31804823-6e5e-4e2d-9729-330d12ccb880/dynamic-sql-stored-proc-with-informationschemacolumns?forum=transactsql) says that this method of combining strings is unsupported.  Although he recommends a cursor in this particular answer, I would use XML.

Comment: Just for the record, this could be helpful to know too: [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx)

Comment: @Pred : Now i understands perfectly with your one line comment ... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CONCAT` function of SQL Server:

```
SELECT @liststr = CONCAT(@liststr, ',', name) FROM comma
SELECT @liststr AS myString
```

So if one parameter in the CONCAT is NULL, it will be replaced by an empty string.